# How does XCM remote locking work?

Tags: xcm, assets

Hey valuable Substrate masterminds,

I wonder how to use this new XCMv3 remote lock feature on a parachain. Consider these references:

- [remote locking tests](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/02905341f7f7d1b3aa1944ccbe3a86072fbf4b06/xcm/xcm-builder/src/tests/locking.rs#L20-L238)
- [Asset lock trait](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/02905341f7f7d1b3aa1944ccbe3a86072fbf4b06/xcm/xcm-executor/src/traits/asset_lock.rs#L62-L123)
- [Remote locking PR by Gavin Wood](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/pull/4945)

Assume a Kusama account used remote locking on Kusama and those funds are able to get unlocked by my parachain. At this point `LockAsset` was used and `NoteUnlockable` is done.

Just a couple of general questions:

If KSM is remote locked on the Kusama chain for my parachain, can the KSM be still staked or can it be used for voting in democracy still?

The unlock can only be made by my parachain if it is remote locked on Kusama. But what if my parachain is evolves to be malicious and never unlocks the KSM of their users. Is the Kusama governance able to unlock the KSM too?

Now to my parachain: Where can I find on-chain the information that an account has locked KSM on Kusama for my chain? If I got the information of the first question, my second question is: If I want to use this for a voting mechanism on my parachain, but I have two different voting mechanisms that should not overlap with the funds: how can I keep track of which funds were already taken out of the remote lock?

If my voting mechanism is allowed to have overlapping funds, then it seems quite easy to implement: I just have to query the information on-chain how many funds have been locked on behalf of my chain. So, the most important question would be the first one: How can I query this on-chain?

Are there any existing remote lock tests for parachains out there? If yes, please provide a reference. I know of XCM transfer tests, which use orml xtokens for an easy XCM interface, but I don't think orml has implemented a similar easy interface for remote locks yet.

How to unlock the remote funds from an account on Kusama from my parachain in my runtime?

What if there are multiple remote locks on Kusama on a specific account for my chain: Are those locks being internally combined, so that my parachain only sees the maximum amount?

Comment: Is there any reference, which already makes active use of this new feature?

Comment: Is it just querying this storage item of pallet_xcm https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/a9b12a13a05c060f4db040d88ffc934b6ad2a180/xcm/pallet-xcm/src/lib.rs#L530-L541 ?

Comment: I think my last question is answered by yes with this https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/a9b12a13a05c060f4db040d88ffc934b6ad2a180/xcm/pallet-xcm/src/lib.rs#L1645

Comment: Please answer your question if you found the answer :)